# Sum of editText value in android by using TextWaxtcher Like a Cash Calculator app in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to develop a **Cash Calculator app** clone. So I am now facing a problem when I enter a value in the editText1 then the app gets crashed.

So, My Question is how can I perform the addition by using the **TextWatcher** of the values of **Three EditText** and display the final **Total** to the **Final Total TextView**. Also, I want to display the value of EditText1 simultaneously on the "T1 TextView". Similarly for the EditText2 and for the EditText3. After displaying the value to T1,T2, and T3. Then get the values of T1 TextView, T2 TextView, and T3 TextView then display it on the **Final Total TextView**

Here is my code that so far I have done.

**This my MainActivity.java  code**

```
package com.dinocodeacademy.cashcalculatordummy;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText1,editText2,editText3;
TextView t1,t2,t3;
TextView txtFinalTotal;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    t1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t2 = findViewById(R.id.t2);
    t3 = findViewById(R.id.t3);
    txtFinalTotal = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    calCulateTotal(); // calling calculate method
    }
});

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    calCulateTotal(); // calling calculate method
    }
});

    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    calCulateTotal(); // calling calculate method
    }
});
}  // end of onCreate() method

private void calCulateTotal(){
   String et1= editText1.getText().toString();
   String et2= editText2.getText().toString();
   String et3= editText3.getText().toString();
   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(et1);
   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(et2);
   int num3 = Integer.parseInt(et3);
   int total = num1 + num2 + num3;
   txtFinalTotal.setText(total);
```

}
}

**This is my activity_main.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#F3E8E8"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.085"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.196" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.085"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.067" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Final Total TextView"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.775" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:text="T1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.775"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="T2"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.36"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/t1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.105" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="T3"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.778"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/t2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the crash in your log?

Comment: Hi Vijay, you need to post your log on your question for others to know what is happening.

Comment: I figured out one thing and sorry for late answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably your crash is because of the case that when you change the value of `editText1` the values of `editText2` and `editText3` are empty, so when you attempt `Integer.parseInt` on it, it raises an exception.

You can try giving a default text of `0` to all `editText1`, `editText2` and `editText3`.

**PS:** I know this can be shared as a comment but my reputation is currently only 41 and I can't post a comment so writing this as an answer.